# Positional arguments and the self keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-object

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last

    def fullname():
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

emp = Employee('Rob', 'M')

print (emp.fullname())
```

You will notice I left out the `self` keyword in the fullname method, so I get:

```
TypeError: fullname() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Is this actually an arguments error? My guess was no so I tried:

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(foo, first, last):
        foo.first = first
        foo.last = last

    def fullname():
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

emp = Employee('rob', 'm')

print(emp.fullname())
```

and a few other things such as leaving self out of the return statement in `fullname()`. However, each method of alteration says the error is a `TypeError`. So I am stumped, why is `fullname()` being passed an argument?

Comment: You forgot `self`. (Also, when posting code, please ensure it exactly matches something you actually ran, including indentation. You can do this by copy-pasting your code into the question box, selecting everything you pasted (including the parts that seem okay in the preview), and hitting Ctrl-K.)

Comment: In the form you posted it in, your code included several indentation bugs that would have resulted in a different error from the one you reported.

Comment: It's important to realize that `self` is not a keyword in Python. It's only convention that the first argument to a method is named `self`. You could use a different name if you wanted to (though you usually shouldn't since it will make your code more confusing to other programmers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
def fullname():
    return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)
```

In the preceding method, what does the variable `self` refer to in `self.first`? How does Python know what you mean when you type `self`?

All methods are implicitly passed their parent object as their first parameter, just like `sys.argv[0]` is always the script name. This is so things like `self.first` can work.

Comment: So fullname(self) is expecting an instance of an object then? Which in this case is emp. So the positional argument it is referring to is the actual instance of Employee itself?

Comment: @Rob yes exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining it as:

```
def fullname(self):
    [...]
```

The `self` argument is implicitly passed in to method calls. It represents a reference to the object on which the method was invoked.

Answer (score 0):

In python the first argument of a class method refers to the current instance of the class. For exemple if you create an emp object using the Employee class:

```
emp = Employee('Rob', 'M')
```

`self` will refer to emp.
So you have to pass `self` as argument of `fullname`.

`def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)`